# Оптимизации запроса c дубликатами

Tags: php, mysql

Добрый вечер.
В общем, пришлось мне столкнуться с таким делом. Есть у меня 2 таблицы. В первой (table1) информация о всех юзерах.
Пример:

```
user_id:3, name:Вася
user_id:5, name:Иван
user_id:6, name:Оля
```

Во второй (table2) - информация о взаимодействиях между этими пользователями.
Пример:

```
user_id:3, his_best_friend_id:5, his_girlfriend_id:6
```

И нужно такое: Вытащить ИМЕНА Васиного лучшего друга и девушки.

Как это вижу я: вытаскиваем из первой таблицы айдишники его лучшего друга и девушки.
Затем, зная айди - делаем еще по одному запросу и вытаскиваем имя обоих. Выглядит это так:

```
$result=mysql_query("SELECT best_friend,girlfriend FROM table2 WHERE user_id='3'");
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)   //тут у нас оказываются айдишники 5 и 6

$friend=mysql_query("SELECT name FROM table1 WHERE user_id='".$row['best_friend']."'");
$his_friend=mysql_fetch_assoc($friend);   //получаем Иван

$girl_friend=mysql_query("SELECT name FROM table1 WHERE user_id='".$row['girlfriend']."'");  //получаем Оля
$his_girl_friend=mysql_fetch_assoc($friend);
```

Так вот проблем не было бы, да таких Вась у меня вытаскивается очень много и всё это идёт через

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {}
```

Я на 99% уверен, что это не самый оптимальный вариант решения такого дела))
Может кто-то знает вариант получше? Буду рад любым ссылкам и наставлениям.

Comment: 'Вася' у вас уникальный?

Comment: оп, пардон, поправил  
Вася не уникальный, user_id уникальный

Comment: Значения я для примера подобрал.. и видимо не самый удачные, т.к. вопреки логики но для лучшего понимания картины добавлю что у юзера каждый день в базу записывается новый лучший друг, и новая девушка. А потом же нужно вытаскивать список имён этих разных друзей и подружек Вася за последние 20 дней.

Comment: Если верить той структуре что вы описали, запрос вида
  SELECT name FROM table2 WHERE user_id
не правилен.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT n.name, g.name as girl, f.name as friend FROM table1 n
join table2 t on t.user_id=n.user_id and n.name='Вася'
join table1 g on t.his_girlfriend_id=g.user_id
join table1 f on t.his_best_friend_id=f.user_id
```

**upd**

если нужно имя 'Васи'

```
SELECT n.name, g.name as girl, f.name as friend FROM table2 t 
join table1 g on t.his_girlfriend_id=g.user_id
join table1 f on t.his_best_friend_id=f.user_id
join table1 n on t.user_id=n.user_id
where  t.user_id=3
```

если имя не нужно:

```
SELECT  g.name as girl, f.name as friend FROM table2 t 
join table1 g on t.his_girlfriend_id=g.user_id
join table1 f on t.his_best_friend_id=f.user_id
where  t.user_id=3
```

**upd:**

[[@Nord001](/users/6627/nord001)](/users/6627/nord001) к моему вопросу коменты кончились, там стоит индекс на user_id поэтому со скоростью всё будет в порядке.

Comment: А поиск по строковому, не уникальному полю не зло? :)

Comment: в принципе в данном запросе совершенно всё равно на уникальность, он вернет правильный результат. но таковы уж условия задачи, видимо в реальной задаче это учтено. либо поиск будет осуществляться по `user_id`

Comment: да-да я же поправил, это я в начале ошибся)  
по user_id поиск идет

Comment: тогда немножко всё упростится, сейчас подправлю

Comment: а как у этого кода дела с вытаскиванием многих людей?
посмотрите первый комментарий под ответом Nord001, пожалуйста.

Comment: Я бы всё таки условие выборки вынес во WHERE. 
MySQL в любом случае упростит но читабельность запроса выше.

Comment: @Denis Masster да вытащит всех ) @Nord001 угу согласен лучше вынести.

Comment: Соглашаюсь, ваш вариант лучше, +1 :)

Если не ошибаюсь, имеет смысл на поля his_girlfriend_id и his_best_friend_id проставить индексы? Это уже к создателю топика, если не сделано ещё.

Comment: ни в коем случае, они же могут дружить между собой )

Comment: понял, спасибо)

Comment: FLK,это вы мне?
Просто если не будет одиночных индексов по этим полям, JOIN будет очень долго выполнятся.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
  (SELECT f.name FROM table1 as f WHERE f.id = table2.his_best_friend_id) as friend,
  (SELECT g.name FROM table1 as g WHERE g.id = table2.his_girlfriend_id) as girlfriend  
FROM
  table2 
WHERE
  table2.user_id='3'
```

Comment: т.е. по сути те же 3 запроса.  
как я уже говорил выше пример не самый удачный.. но представим что каждый день Васе в базу записывается новый лучший друг и подружка.  
И нужно вытащить список 20 имён Васиных лучших друзей и подружек за последние 20 дней. Это для каждого дня нужно будет вот эти 3 запроса делать? Нельзя както сразу вытащить все 20 имен друга as friend и 20 подружек as girlfriend ?

Comment: вложенные селекты зло...

Comment: ну данный пример вытащит всех подружек и друзей.

а также, как выше написали про "зло вложенных селектов" - честно говоря не уверен в этом но и не опровергаю, сам не проверял.

Comment: спасибо)   .