# Нужны ли индексы на поля участвующие в join

Tags: mysql

В продолжении [вопроса](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/101562/%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B0)

Такой запрос:

```
SELECT n.name, g.name as girl, f.name as friend FROM table2 t 
join table1 g on t.his_girlfriend_id=g.user_id
join table1 f on t.his_best_friend_id=f.user_id
join table1 n on t.user_id=n.user_id
where  t.user_id=3
```

Нужны ли индексы на поля

```
  t.his_girlfriend_id и t.his_best_friend_id
```

**UPD**

Видимо, в [том вопросе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/101562/%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B0) не совсем видно :) но я знаю что индексы тут нужны, точнее я их туда точно поставил бы. Просто меня удивил ответ [@FLK](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/6551/flk), что они там не нужны. Вот и хочу понять кто прав :)

И, если никто не против, будем рассматривать **MyISAM**, т.к. он всё ещё пока самый популярный.

Comment: нет не нужны, к примеру (относительно задачи) есть маша с которой дружат вася, петя, коля. вася же дружит с машей и петей. при использовании индексов, вася уже не сможет дружить с петей после того как с петей подружила маша ) а вот индексы на user_id обязательны.

Comment: Как я понял, там что-то похожее на "Историю взаимоотношений", так что в теории  результат table2.user_id=3 может быть неограниченно большим....

Comment: Странный вопрос, конечно же нужны. Посмотрите план запроса и всё своими глазами увидите.

Comment: это конечно мало связано с mysql, но все же... томас кайт (очень известный специалист по оракл) очень хорошо разжевывает тему "нужны индексы или нет". думаю, те же аргументы, за и против, применимы к другим субд (возможно не все, но подавляющее большинство наверняка)

Comment: Для такого запроса **не нужны**, т.к. where фиксирует строку из t, а далее идет выборка из table1 по user_id.

Ну, это если оптимизатор в мускуле разумно запрограммирован.

Comment: @Nord001, поймите простую вещь: MySQL (да и по идеи любая реляционная БД) одновременно для одной (суб)выборки может использовать **только один индекс**. По этому, даже если вы поставите индексы на `t.his_girlfriend` и `t.his_best_friend_id` MySQL выберет уникальный индекс по `t.user_id`, поскольку он более предпочтителен по очевидным причинам.

Comment: Безотносительно данного случая, кстати говоря, увлекаться индексами, особенно составными, не стоит. СУБД может выбрать неэффективный план запроса. Индекс - подсказка для СУБД как лучше выбирать записи, если "подсказок" будет слишком много или "подсказки" будут слишком объемными можно прийти к противоположному результату, т.е. запрос может стать менее эффективным чем даже без индексов вовсе.

Comment: @Nord001, (отвечу здесь, ибо квота) я не изменил своего мнения и таки рекомендую посмотреть на план, чтобы убедиться и была образовательная польза от всего написанного. 

> PHP - потому что много хороших разработчиков

Хороших ли? Или всё-таки качество замещают количеством?

> И им проще(Фейсбуку) написать перекомпилятор в СИ чем изначально на чём-то другом писать

В корне неверно. У них уже есть тонны пхпешного говнокода, который тормозит и глючит, обеспечивая им гигантские счета за электричество и прочие расходы серверных ферм. Рефакторить, а тем более переписывать не хватит никаких средств

Comment: @Ilya Pirogov, база на MySQL с MyISAM не является реляционной БД по определению. @Yura Ivanov, ерунду говорите. Индекс - не "подсказка", а предварительно просчитанная часть операции сравнения. @jmu, я думаю, ссылка на asktom была бы уместна в качестве ответа.

Comment: > база на MySQL с MyISAM не является реляционной БД по определению

@karmadro4, что за ахинею вы несете? [Реляционная СУБД](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%A1%D0%A3%D0%91%D0%94)

Comment: @karmadro4 буквоедством не страдайте. кавычки в слове "подсказка" были мной использованы как раз для вас, а вы читаете буквально.

Планов запроса может быть великое множество, выбор оптимального плана остается за СУБД, если вы настаиваете, что при оптимальном плане будет использован индекс по подружкам, то это значит что план будет таким: fullscan по таблице table1, затем индекс по his_girlfriend, затем индекс по table2.user_id. это неоптимальный план. он может быть выбран, например когда таблицы содержат "мало" записей, и fullscan работает быстрее чем индекс, но речь не про этот случай.

Comment: @Yura Ivanov, давайте отбросим "неопределенный" случай, когда при неизвестном для нас N строк результата оптимизатор будет считать full scan выгоднее, чем index scan. В противном случае придется сравнивать каждый из наборов строк с N, выполняя вручную работу оптимизатора. Таким образом index scan (индекс является предварительно построенным упорядоченным деревом поиска) всегда будет выгоднее, чем full scan. 
Или вы ссылаетесь на какой-то хронический баг оптимизатора, от которого он путается?

@Ilya Pirogov, почитайте свою же ссылку про отношения.

Comment: @karmadro4, в моем ответе, чуть ниже этого комментария, нет ничего про фуллскан. фуллскан будет в вашем плане, чтоб сработал индекс по подружкам. в оптимальном плане выполнение поиска записей будет идти в обратном, предполагаемому вами, пути. т.к использование кластерного индекса в joinах предпочтительнее некластерного индекса по подружкам. и без фуллскана.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Конкретно для этого запроса индексы по `t.his_girlfriend_id` и `t.his_best_friend_id` использоваться не будут. Индексы предотвращают full scan таблицы, эффективно позволяя выбирать записи с конкретными значениями. В данном случае будет применен индекс по `table2.user_id`, затем для каждой отфильтрованной записи будут выбраны значения для для каждого из join'ов из table1 и будут использованы индексы по `table1.user_id`.

Однако, если в дальнейшем вам понадобится по девушке найти ее парня (у парня будет his_girlfriend_id = эта девушка), то индекс пригодится.

Answer (score 1):

По хорошему, нужны не только индексы по этим полям, а еще и [внешние ключи](http://www.mysql.ru/docs/man/ANSI_diff_Foreign_Keys.html). Все поля, которые используются в условиях и сортировке желательно индексировать. Индексы существенно ускоряют выборку в больших таблицах, а внешние ключи отвечают за проверку целостности данных.

Comment: MySQL - игрушечная DBMS, и на этой платформе не принято строить реляционные базы. А в дооракловские времена возможность FK была недоступна "из коробки", а только в виде опции с другой лицензией.

Comment: @karmadro4, кем "не принято"?

Реляционные связи в MySQL существует с 2000-го года. Именно тогда с версией 3.23 в сборку вошел табличный движок InnoDB, который, в числе прочего, реализует встроенную поддержку Foreign Keys.

А на счет того, что MySQL - игрушечная СУБД, скажите фейсбуку и вконтакту. Это ж нада было так протупить...

Comment: Не принято у пхпешников, которые являются подавляющим большинством пользователей MySQL. И очевидно, что им наплевать на ссылочную целостность и прочую ACID-заумь. С 2000-го года прошло десять лет использования плоских файлов MyISAM, до версии 5.5 с InnoDB по умолчанию (и то благодаря инициативе Oracle).

> скажите фейсбуку и вконтакту

Они используют InnoDB?

Comment: Категоричные заявления про "всех пхпешников" и "MySQL - игрушечная DBMS" неплохо бы подкрепить пруфлинками на авторитетные ресурсы. В противном случае эти слова гроша ломанного не стоят.

> очевидно, что им наплевать на ссылочную целостность и прочую ACID-заумь

Не очевидно. Судя по вопросам "нужны ли индексы", гораздо очевиднее то, что это результат неопытности и, как следствие, непонимания разницы.

> Они используют InnoDB?

Они используют MySQL, которая, как вы выразились - "игрушечная DBMS".

Comment: > Они используют MySQL

То есть, вы не знаете, а "знаменитостей" помянули авторитета ради? И с меня теперь требуете АИ? Ну-ну. Не удивлюсь, если окажется, что справедливо обратное, и они используют MySQL потому, что привыкли, лицензия бесплатна и плоские файлы MyISAM обеспечивают приемлемую скорость. А про ссылочную целостность кодеры не слышали никогда или в лучшем случае считают дополнительным источником ошибок исполнения :-)

> про "всех пхпешников"

Такого я не писал. 

> результат неопытности и, как следствие, непонимания разницы

В мире PHP это норма.

Comment: Ссылки на источники, подтверждающие ваши высказывания, нужны не мне, а, в первую очередь, автору топика. Потому что вы, своими комментами в категоричной форме, неявно критикуете выбор технологий, который он сделал. А он, в силу своей неопытности, может принять эти высказывания за чистую монету.

И вот не нужно всех под одну гребенку. Быдлокод это не нормы PHP, это плата за низкий порог вхождения. А "знаменитостей" я привел в пример потому что это высокотехнологичные проекты, где нет места дилетантам, и в основе которых лежат те самые решения, что вы назвали "игрушечными".

Comment: [@karmadro4][1] Вышеупомянутые социальные сети используют PHP и MySQL. 
PHP - потому что много хороших разработчиков и скорость разработки выше. И им проще(Фейсбуку) написать перекомпилятор в СИ чем изначально на чём-то другом писать. 
Справедливости ради надо сказать что используют они не MySQL из коробке, а пропатчённе, где-то в сети была статьи с конференций, где в общих чертах описывали их инфраструктуру.


Как я понял, вы тоже считаете что индексы там точно нужны?

  [1]: http://hashcode.ru/users/6679/karmadro4

Comment: > А он, в силу своей неопытности, может принять эти высказывания за чистую монету.

Напоминаю, ваши рассуждения про внешние ключи в MySQL, с которых всё началось, не несут смысловой нагрузки без InnoDB. А реалии таковы, что тотальная миграция с MyISAM еще не случилась. Так что не вам говорить о пустословии.

> это высокотехнологичные проекты, где нет места дилетантам

Ох, ЛОЛ. Действительно, к**а**смические технологии. Хотя, возможен и более мрачный сценарий, в котором в уголках Дурова действительно сидят высокие профессионалы, а медиана бегает на воле.

Разочарован и прощаюсь (квота!).

Comment: При чем тут миграция с MyISAM на InnoDB? Это имеет смысл только при сопровождении старых проектов.

И еще. Одно дело - говнокод по неопытности, и другое, когда его пропагандируют такие вот "специалисты". Первый вариант лечится чтением мануалов и практикой, а во втором - рекомендую убица об стену.